# Display Time Zone with name of place and time in GMT Using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am developing a website which need a dropdown for displaying time zone with the name of the place. It may be a directive or something else. Any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When it is about the Time related things i always preferred to use **[Moment.Js](https://momentjs.com/)**. It works perfect with Angular, I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

download jstz.min.js (see [the bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) for more info) and add a function to your html page and implement this code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function getTimezoneName() {
        timezone = jstz.determine()
        return timezone.name();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you should edit your post to have that link instead of adding a comment...I have done this now...

Comment: you need to implement that script in your component

Comment: if you find any difficulties, please post your code here and feel free to contact me.

Comment: if i implement the code jstz is undefined what is jstz

Comment: download this  jstz.min.js. it is a library.
create a file jstz.min.js and copy and paste the code from the below link,
https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/52971-102-1-171969/jstz-1.0.4.min.js

Comment: I want the entire dropdown and the user may choose the location is what i need